# How to restore file or theme?

Tags: themes, pages

Accidentally messed up page.php in Twenty Twelve theme. How do I replace it with the original file, or reinstall the theme?

Answer (score 3):

download the twentytwelve theme here 
http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve

unpack the files and take the page.php file and upload it to the wp-content/themes/twentytwelve folder overwriting the one that is there